# separating multiple words out of the same index

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I have a list with multiple words per index, and i need to split the words into different indexes.

```
mylist = ['hell o', 'geg gg' etc...]
```

How do i turn the above list into.

```
newList = ['hell', 'o' , 'geg', 'gg']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
In [192]: mylist = ['hell o', 'geg gg']

In [193]: [part for item in mylist for part in item.split()]
Out[193]: ['hell', 'o', 'geg', 'gg']
```

---

```
[part for item in mylist for part in item.split()]
```

is equivalent to to the value assigned to `result` by

```
result = list()
for item in mylist:
    for part in item.split():
        result.append(part)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing it

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> mylist = ['hell o', 'geg gg']
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(map(str.split, mylist)))
['hell', 'o', 'geg', 'gg']
```